# TabView перекрывается аппаратными кнопками устройства

Tags: java, android

Собственно проблема. Каким образом можно нижний tabView поставить сверху кнопок (назад, домой и тд). Если их скрыть, все нормально показывается и никаких проблем нет, но мне они в приложении нужны.

[image: view]

Разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <!-- Your normal content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <!-- We use a Toolbar so that our drawer can be displayed
             in front of the action bar -->
        <customviews.CustomToolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/phone_toolbar"
            android:id="@+id/drawer_toolbar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:background="@color/ab_background"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            >

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="@dimen/homeIconContainerSize"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@color/blueRawLight"
                >

                <customviews.HomeImageView
                    android:id="@+id/openMenu"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_drawer" />


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="18dp"
                    android:layout_height="18dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="end|right|top"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    >
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:id="@+id/badger_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="top"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle_badge">

                    </LinearLayout>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/badger"
                    android:layout_width="16dp"
                    android:layout_height="16dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:text="12"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
                </RelativeLayout>

            </FrameLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

            </LinearLayout>

        </customviews.CustomToolbar>

        <!-- The rest of your content view -->

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentFrame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/phone_toolbar"
            >
        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            />

        <customviews.SlidingTabLayout
            android:background="@color/ab_background"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/sliding_height" />

            <customviews.RoundToggleButton
                android:layout_width="@dimen/filter_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/filter_size"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:background="@drawable/presence_offline"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_search_min"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/search_filter">
            </customviews.RoundToggleButton>

            <customviews.RoundToggleButton
                app:borderWidth="0dp"
                xmlns:FilterState="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/ru.digipeople.omnicomm"
                FilterState:filterchecked="true"

                android:id="@+id/offline_fiter"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/filter_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/filter_size"
                android:background="@drawable/presence_busy"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_below="@+id/search_filter"
                />

            <customviews.RoundToggleButton
                app:borderWidth="0dp"
                xmlns:FilterState="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/ru.digipeople.omnicomm"
                FilterState:filterchecked="true"
                android:id="@+id/online_filter"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/filter_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/filter_size"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:background="@drawable/presence_online"
                app:elevation="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_below="@+id/search_filter"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/search_filter"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/search_filter" />


    </FrameLayout>

    <include
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/phone_toolbar"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/sliding_height"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/incl_progress_container" />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        style="@style/customExpandableList"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Без разметки, стилей и ссылки на либу вам не помочь

Comment: просто, что может вызывать такую проблему ? 
Если скидывать исходники сюда, это очень много кода.

Comment: Скорее всего у вас что-то не так с высотой элементов в разметке

Comment: но если панель кнопок скрыть, все становится нормально. Я ведь как понимаю, при наличии кнопок, табы должны быть над ней, а если мы их скрываем, то оставаться внизу экрана. Но это не происходит. Кнопки живут сами по себе.

Comment: Да, в теории так всё и должно быть. Но раз у вас не так, значит что-то где-то не так. Но что - неизвестно, ведь нам не видно кода/разметки/стилей/либы

Comment: у вас что-то не так с разметкой. Простите, но хрустальный шар вчера разбился, и я не могу нагадать, что именно. Поэтому вам все же придется показать вашу разметку, если вы хотите помощи.

Comment: я добавил разметку в вопрос :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вдруг вы не найдете ошибку, если она конечно же есть, вот пару методов что  бы определить наличии и высоту этих кнопок, а потом установить для вашего веб-вью маржин или падинг:

```
    /**Method for detect NavigationBar size
     * on devices as Nexus.
     *
     * @param context - application context
     * @return - {@link Point} with navBar size
     */
    public static Point getNavigationBarSize(Context context) {
        Point appUsableSize = getAppUsableScreenSize(context);
        Point realScreenSize = getRealScreenSize(context);

        // navigation bar on the right
        if (appUsableSize.x < realScreenSize.x) {
            return new Point(realScreenSize.x - appUsableSize.x, appUsableSize.y);
        }

        // navigation bar at the bottom
        if (appUsableSize.y < realScreenSize.y) {
            return new Point(appUsableSize.x, realScreenSize.y - appUsableSize.y);
        }

        // navigation bar is not present
        return new Point();
    }

    public static boolean isNavBarAviable(Context context){
        boolean b = false;
        Point point = getNavigationBarSize(context);
        if (point.y > 0 ){ b = true; }
        return b;
    }
```

Comment: или так еще можно
  `Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
  Point size = new Point();
  display.getSize(size);
  getWindow().setLayout(size.x, size.y);`